# Game center distance-based match-making?

Tags: iphone, ios, game-center

Suppose that I want to match people only if they're within some distance apart by GPS coordinates. Is this possible through game center?

Or, if my app has the GPS coordinates of the players and their game center profiles, does matchmaking allow me to specify a non-friend player to invite?

Thanks